# How to determine whether a program uses DirectX, and if so, what's the DirectX surface size?

Tags: c#, directx, screenshot

I'm using [Spazzarama's](https://github.com/spazzarama/Direct3DHook) Direct3DHook to capture screenshots from an application (with the purpose of streaming them over the Internet). Although this works well when the application uses DirectX, it fails if the application does not use DirectX (e.g. Notepad).

1. How can I determine whether a running application (process) uses DirectX? The reason is that in that case, I would need to use a different way to capture a screen, e.g. using GDI+.
2. When this DirectX application is not running in full screen mode, how do I get the size of the DirectX surface? E.g. when I capture the screen of a game running in windowed mode, the application size includes the size of the window frame etc. too, and my captured screen is typically too large.